# Get the latest record for each employee older than a given date

Tags: mysql

I have a status history table that also includes future dated records.

Example: employee_jobs

```
id | employee_id | division_id | department_id | job_id | effective_date
1     100          1             1               1        2015-01-01
2     100          1             1               2        2016-01-01
3     100          1             2               4        2017-01-01
4     200          1             3               5        2016-01-01
5     300          1             3               6        2015-01-01
6     300          1             3               7        2016-05-25
```

I need a preforming SQL that will show a given employee_id's current live record when given a date: Example Date = 2016-08-15

The result set should be:

```
id | employee_id | division_id | department_id | job_id | effective_date
2     100          1             1               2        2016-01-01
4     200          1             3               5        2016-01-01
6     300          1             3               7        2016-05-25
```

Comment: How do you define `current live record` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want records for each employee having the latest `effective_date` with a **constraint**

***(`effective_date` must be less than or equal to a given date)***

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@sameEmployee = employee_id, @rn := @rn + 1,
         IF(@sameEmployee := employee_id, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
     ) AS row_number
    FROM employee_jobs
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameEmployee := 0, @rn := 1) var
    WHERE effective_date <= '2016-08-15'
    ORDER BY employee_id, effective_date DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number = 1
ORDER BY t.employee_id
```